# Translating array pointer access from C++ to Delphi

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi, pointers, memory-address

I'd like to know if I translated a piece of code correctly from C++ to Delphi.
It looks like it is working, but I have a feeling that I'm reading and writing into memory that I'm not supposed to using Delphi.

Given C++ code:

```
struct tile_map
{
    int32 CountX;
    int32 CountY;

    uint32 *Tiles;
};

inline uint32
GetTileValueUnchecked(tile_map *TileMap, int32 TileX, int32 TileY)
{
    uint32 TileMapValue = TileMap->Tiles[TileY*TileMap->CountX + TileX];
    return(TileMapValue);
}

uint32 Tiles00[9][17] =
    {
        {1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    };
// More tile map declarations ...   
// uint32 Tiles01[9][17] = ...
// uint32 Tiles10[9][17] = ...
// uint32 Tiles11[9][17] = ...  

    tile_map TileMaps[2][2];
    TileMaps[0][0].CountX = 17;
    TileMaps[0][0].CountY = 9;
    TileMaps[0][0].Tiles = (uint32 *)Tiles00;

    TileMaps[0][1] = TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[0][1].Tiles = (uint32 *)Tiles01;

    TileMaps[1][0] = TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[1][0].Tiles = (uint32 *)Tiles10;

    TileMaps[1][1] = TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[1][1].Tiles = (uint32 *)Tiles11;

// Usage
    int32 PlayerTileX = 2;
    int32 PlayerTileY = 2;
    uint32 TileMapValue = GetTileValueUnchecked(&TileMap[1][1], PlayerTileX, PlayerTileY);
```

Delphi translation:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
    Puint32 = ^uint32;

    tile_map = record
        CountX : int32;
        CountY : int32;

        Tiles : Puint32;
    end;
    Ptile_map = ^tile_map;

{$POINTERMATH ON}   
function GetTileValueUnchecked(TileMap : Ptile_map; TileX, TileY : int32) : uint32; inline;
begin
    result := TileMap^.Tiles[TileY * TileMap^.CountX + TileX];
end;


const //in the future these will be read from file, so const for now
    Tiles00:  array [0..8, 0..16] of uint32 =
    (
        (1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
        (1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    );
    // More tile map declarations ...
    //Tiles01:  array [0..8, 0..16] of uint32 = ...
    //Tiles10:  array [0..8, 0..16] of uint32 = ...
    //Tiles11:  array [0..8, 0..16] of uint32 = ...
var 
    TileMaps : array [0..1, 0..1] of  tile_map;
    PlayerTileX, PlayerTileY : int32;
    TileMapValue : uint32;
begin

    TileMaps[0][0].CountX := 17;
    TileMaps[0][0].CountY := 9;
    TileMaps[0][0].Tiles := Addr(Tiles00);

    TileMaps[0][1] := TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[0][1].Tiles := Addr(Tiles01);

    TileMaps[1][0] := TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[1][0].Tiles := Addr(Tiles10);

    TileMaps[1][1] := TileMaps[0][0];
    TileMaps[1][1].Tiles := Addr(Tiles11);

    // Usage
    PlayerTileX := 2;
    PlayerTileY := 2;
    TileMapValue = GetTileValueUnchecked(@TileMaps[1][1], PlayerTileX, PlayerTileY);
end.
```

Comment: This really belongs on the code review SE site. I suggest you re-post there. Using `@` is more idiomatic that `Addr`. The code looks good to me though. You've got the concepts just right. I haven't checked that you got all the indices correct. You can do that.

Comment: It did not occur to me to use the @ on a constant, thanks.
I was not aware that there was a code review SE site. I think I have to wait 90 min before I can post there.

Comment: If you are in a hurry you could write some unit tests for your code.  You should be able to satisfy yourself you have it right fairly easily, I would have thought.

Comment: As I said, it seems to work, I was just curious to know if what I did was considered to be correct or not.

Comment: Looks fine to me too. But I prefer Addr, sometimes, if it is not very certain, or only doable with lots of parentheses, to which part of an expression the @ applies.  The Addr() function-like syntax makes this much clearer, IMO.

Comment: @Rudy `@Tiles00` is looking pretty unambiguous from here.  ;-)  And `@` is just a unary operator with a defined precedence and associativity. If you can't remember off the top of your head what those are, there is nothing stopping you adding parens to make it clear. You can perfectly well write `@(arr[i])[j]` just as you write `addr(arr[i])[j]`.

Comment: @David: I didn't mean here, just in general. Sometimes Addr() can make expressions more readable, IMO I find `Addr(a[I])[13]` more readable than `(@a[i])[13]`, which look a lot like `@a[i][13]`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis It's the parens that do that, which you can use anyway. Once you have the parens then it's 50/50 in my view.

Answer (score 0):

David Heffernan's comments has been helpful and others seem to agree that the code is correct, so I will mark this as answered.